# How to use first_value() window function to get last non null value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to perform a fill-down operation in Postgres.

DDL:

```
create table brands (
id int,
category varchar(20),
brand_name varchar(20)
);

insert into brands values
 (1,'chocolates','5-star')
,(2,null,'dairy milk')
,(3,null,'perk')
,(4,null,'eclair')
,(5,'Biscuits','britannia')
,(6,null,'good day')
,(7,null,'boost')
,(8,'shampoo','h&s')
,(9,null,'dove')
;
```

Expected output is:

| category | brand_name |
| --- | --- |
| chocolates | 5-star |
| chocolates | dairy milk |
| chocolates | perk |
| chocolates | eclair |
| Biscuits | britannia |
| Biscuits | good day |
| Biscuits | boost |
| Shampoo | h&s |
| Shampoo | dove |

I tried using the following script but it doesn't seem to work.

```
select id,
      first_value(category)
      over(order by case when category is not null then id end desc nulls last) as category,
      brand_name
from brands
```

Can someone suggest a fix?
In MS SQL the following snippet seems to work fine:

```
select id,
       first_value (category) IGNORE NULLS
       over(order by id desc
        rows between current row and unbounded following) as category,
       brand_name
FROM brands
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Take a look at [Migrate Your Mindset Too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). That just might be the most important thing when migrating to another Database manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with cte as (
select id,
       category,
       count(category) over (order by id) as category_id,
       brand_name
  from brands)
select id,
       first_value(category) over (partition by category_id order by id) as category,
       brand_name
  from cte;
```

UPDATE: added query without CTE per request:

```
select id,
       (array_agg(category) over (order by id))[max(case when category is null then 0 else id end) over (order by id)] as category,
       brand_name
  from brands;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Although I'm aware of this approach, but what if I do not want to use a cte as an intermediate step. I would just like to use a single window function to solve this(just as the ms sql solution i mentioned)

Comment: @RishavGhosh: what's wrong with using a CTE?

Answer (score 2):

I think there's nothing wrong with using a `CTE` (see JHH's answer) and I would **prefer** that.

Postgres DB's don't provide this `IGNORE NULLS` concept of SQLServer DB's, so I guess you should stop thinking you will get a nearly identic query for Postgres DB's like in MS SQL.

Anyway, if you don't want to use a CTE or complex subquery, you can define your own function and aggregation and run this.

Function creation:

```
-- CREATE your function
CREATE FUNCTION yourFunction(STATE anyelement, VALUE anyelement)
    RETURNS anyelement
    IMMUTABLE PARALLEL safe
AS
$$
SELECT COALESCE(VALUE, STATE); -- Replace NULL values here
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Aggregate creation using the function:

```
-- CREATE your aggregate
CREATE AGGREGATE yourAggregate(ANYELEMENT) (
    sfunc = yourFunction, -- Call your function here
    stype = ANYELEMENT
);
```

Your query using this aggregate:

```
SELECT id, 
  yourAggregate(category) -- Call your aggregate here
  OVER (ORDER BY id, category), 
  brand_name
FROM brands
ORDER BY id;
```

Of course, you should rename both function and aggregate and use more meaningful names.

This will produce the same outcome like the CTE version.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0VqgCAG5)

If you are keen on defining and using own functions and you will use that often, you could do that.

Otherwise, just use a CTE, that's quite fine. There is no reason to do not use CTE's.

Always be aware that while using own functions, you are on **risk of bad performance**, so you should check whether this query is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that's **not implemented in Postgres** (at least up to Postgres 15). The [manual about window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

> The SQL standard defines a `RESPECT NULLS` or `IGNORE NULLS` option
> for `lead`, `lag`, `first_value`, `last_value`, and `nth_value`. This
> is not implemented in PostgreSQL: the behavior is always the same as
> the standard's default, namely `RESPECT NULLS`.

So you have to use a workaround with a CTE or subquery like JHH suggested, or roll your own window function (which will be comparatively slow).

See (answer to similar question on dba.SE):

- [Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186244/3684)

Answer (score -2):

```
select *, max(category) over (partition by r) 
from(
select *,sum(case when category is not null then 1 end) over (order by rn) r
from
(select *,row_number() over() as rn from brands) l
)p
```