# How can I tell the SQL planner that a WHERE condition in the main query should be executed in the subqueries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance, query-planner

I am using Postgres 14.x.

I have a complex query that can be observed, next to it's EXPLAIN ANALYZE, [here](https://www.pgexplain.dev/plan/e7571192-ee79-4e0f-8275-6db8727fc363).

```sql
select *
from (select * from public.select_version_of_projects('2024-03-08T08:31:08.280Z')) as "project_version"
where "project_version"."id" = 'fd18211b-a400-49ed-a723-9648ab05ca4f';
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.select_version_of_projects(version_p TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                id             UUID,
                folder_id      UUID,
                name           TEXT,
                description    TEXT,
                picture        TEXT,
                files          JSON,
                keywords       TSVECTOR,
                scene          JSON,
                view           JSON,
                credits        JSON,
                published      JSON,
                imports        JSON,
                settings       JSON,
                studio_version TEXT,
                readonly       BOOLEAN,
                deleted        BOOLEAN,
                created_at     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
                updated_at     TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
            )
AS
$$
    SELECT  COALESCE(past.id, present.id)                         AS id,
            COALESCE(past.folder_id, present.folder_id)           AS folder_id,
            COALESCE(past.name, present.name)                     AS name,
            COALESCE(past.description, present.description)       AS description,
            COALESCE(past.picture, present.picture)               AS picture,
            COALESCE(past.files, present.files)                   AS files,
            COALESCE(past.keywords, present.keywords)             AS keywords,
            COALESCE(past.scene, present.scene)                   AS scene,
            COALESCE(past.view, present.view)                     AS view,
            COALESCE(past.credits, present.credits)               AS credits,
            COALESCE(past.published, present.published)           AS published,
            COALESCE(past.imports, present.imports)               AS imports,
            COALESCE(past.settings, present.settings)             AS settings,
            COALESCE(past.studio_version, present.studio_version) AS studio_version,
            COALESCE(past.readonly, present.readonly)             AS readonly,
            COALESCE(past.deleted, present.deleted)               AS deleted,
            COALESCE(past.created_at, present.created_at)         AS created_at,
            COALESCE(past.updated_at, present.updated_at)         AS updated_at
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM project) AS present
    FULL OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT history.project.id,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.folder_id ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.folder_id IS NOT NULL))[1]           AS folder_id,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.name ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.name IS NOT NULL))[1]                     AS name,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.description ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.description IS NOT NULL))[1]       AS description,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.picture ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.picture IS NOT NULL))[1]               AS picture,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.files ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.files IS NOT NULL))[1]                   AS files,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.keywords ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.keywords IS NOT NULL))[1]             AS keywords,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.scene ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.scene IS NOT NULL))[1]                   AS scene,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.view ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.view IS NOT NULL))[1]                     AS view,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.credits ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.credits IS NOT NULL))[1]               AS credits,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.published ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.published IS NOT NULL))[1]           AS published,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.imports ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.imports IS NOT NULL))[1]               AS imports,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.settings ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.settings IS NOT NULL))[1]             AS settings,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.studio_version ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.studio_version IS NOT NULL))[1] AS studio_version,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.readonly ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.readonly IS NOT NULL))[1]             AS readonly,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.deleted ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.deleted IS NOT NULL))[1]               AS deleted,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.created_at ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.created_at IS NOT NULL))[1]         AS created_at,
                  (ARRAY_AGG(history.project.updated_at ORDER BY history.project.recorded_at) FILTER (WHERE history.project.updated_at IS NOT NULL))[1]         AS updated_at
          FROM history.project
          WHERE history.project.recorded_at > version_p
          GROUP BY history.project.id) AS past
    ON present.id = past.id
    WHERE COALESCE(past.created_at, present.created_at) < version_p;
$$
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE;
```

The purpose of the `history` table is to record the changes to each row in the `public` table so that we can always know the past states. And the function basically gives you a table representing the state of the `public` table at the timestamp provided.

Calculating what the whole table looked like in the past is very expensive, but my intention is that by using the function alongside a filter for the ID of the row I want then just that row will be calculated. But that is not happening.

It is very slow. It should take a few milliseconds. But instead of executing the filter `"id" = 'fd18211b-a400-49ed-a723-9648ab05ca4f'` at the first scans to vastly reduce the number of rows fetched so that the aggregation node would be much faster, it is doing it at the end.

If I replace `COALESCE(past.id, present.id) AS id` to either `past.id AS id` or `present.id AS id`, it's fix as can be seen [here](https://www.pgexplain.dev/plan/d70a913d-671f-46d6-9be1-d22ea44184e5), but it's not correct because `past.id` or `present.id` could be `NULL`.

But if `past.id` is `NULL` it means all of `past.*` is NULL. Same with `present`. So it is valid to apply the filter to the subqueries still.

So how can I keep the COALESCE while informing the planner that it should apply the filter to the subqueries?

Comment: your best best ( and probably only one) is to pass the date as parameter to your function as well. otherwise. also using select * is almost never a good idea

Comment: Looks like an indexing issue, `removed by filter` is out of control. Make sure all the filtering can be done using the indexes.

Comment: Maybe a lateral join? Hard to say without full table and index definitions, and the actual query.

Comment: First, I would pass `"project_version"."id" = 'fd18211b-a400-49ed-a723-9648ab05ca4f'` as a parameter of the function, so it has a chance of doing a push down of the filter. Second I would use lateral queries rathat semi-aggregations that discard most of the information read.

Comment: Please consider instructions for [\[postgresql-performance\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) questions!

Comment: @eshirvana The date is already passed to the function as a parameter. What are you trying to say?
And what's the problem with `select *`? I want the whole row.

@FrankHeikens I don't think that's the main issue. You can see how the aggregate node is even slower. And also how by removing the COALESCE results in a Bitmap Index Scan that causes no other filtering to be necessary.

Comment: @Charlieface You can see the actual query already. The `public.project` table structure matches the function return structure. `history.project` is the same but with a `recorded_at` column. Primary keys of (id) and (id, recorded_at) respectively.

Comment: I've edited the links in my post because I noticed a mistake in the function definition. `updated_at` was used instead of `recorded_at` in some places.

Comment: No I can't see a query. I don't want you to just describe the query, I want you to show it.

Comment: @Charlieface In any of the links, at the top left there are 4 tabs. One of them is the QUERY.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Postgres can [inline](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) the function in the calling query (which is often not possible for a set-returning function), it is a black box to the query planner. Everything inside the function is planned and executed separately from the outer query, and the result is materialized before proceeding with the outer query. A worst-case scenario for you.

To apply the all-important filter on ID as early as possible, pass it to the function, and apply it at the root(s).

Plus, don't `array_agg()` all rows, when you just need the latest not-null value. I show a solution using `UNION ALL` instead of your `FULL OUTER JOIN`, order once in the subquery, and aggregate with the function **`first()`** from the additional [first_last_agg](https://github.com/wulczer/first_last_agg) module, which you must have installed first.
The extension is [not available on Amazon RDS Postgres](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html#postgresql-extensions-16x). But you can create the aggregate function yourself. It's simple, see:

- [Get values from first and last row per group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173081/939860)

Details and alternatives in this related answer:

- [Select most recent non-null value for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77682362/select-most-recent-non-null-value-for-multiple-columns/77682882#77682882)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.select_version_of_project(_id uuid, _ts timestamptz)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    id             uuid
  , folder_id      uuid
  , name           text
--, etc.

  )
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
$func$
SELECT p.id
     , first(p.folder_id) FILTER (WHERE p.folder_id IS NOT NULL) AS folder_id
     , first(p.name)      FILTER (WHERE p.name IS NOT NULL)      AS name
--   , etc.
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   history.project h
   WHERE  h.id = _id
   AND    h.updated_at <= _ts  -- ?

   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM   public.project p
   WHERE  p.id = _id
   AND    p.updated_at <= _ts  -- ?

   ORDER  BY updated_at DESC  -- !! I assume you want the latest state
   ) p
GROUP  BY 1;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT *
FROM   public.select_version_of_project ('fd18211b-a400-49ed-a723-9648ab05ca4f'
                                       , '2024-03-08 08:31:08.280+0')  -- timestamptz !
```

Your filters on `created_at` and `updated_at` were not all clear to me. You may have to do more there.

Be sure to have a **multicolumn index** on `history.project(id, updated_at)`!
Not sure about `public.project` - there an index on just `(id)` should suffice, and should already exist as PK index.

Pass a `timestamptz` value as declared or you may get surprising conversions.

Comment: The function is being inlined here. You can see it in the [example](https://www.pgexplain.dev/plan/612df49a-36b9-42d6-9a78-c2544705fad0) where I removed the COALESCE of IDs.
But I'll experiment with the alternative you presented. Although I think I don't have access to the `first_last_agg` module. It's not a pure Postgres DB but an Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL.

Comment: `first_last_agg` is currently not available on Amazon RDS. I added more pointers above.